# openxlsx workbook: multiple hyperlinks in one cell

Tags: r, openxlsx

I've unsuccessfully attempted to add multiple hyperlinks in the same Excel cell with the `openxlsx` package (it's important for me to use `openxlsx` because of the rest of my workflow).

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Could you please include a reproducible example showing what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a combination of stingr package's str_glue and specifying a wrap text style or set column widths? The str_glue allows a "hard return". I'm not sure if the hyperlink is working though, I don't have excel to fully test it.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(stringr)
x <- str_glue("https://www.google.com
              https://www.yahoo.com")

class(x) <- "hyperlink"

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")
wraptext <- createStyle(wrapText = TRUE)


## External Hyperlink

writeData(wb, sheet = 1, x = x, startCol = 10)

addStyle(wb, "Sheet1", wraptext, cols = 10, rows = 1)
setColWidths(wb, "Sheet1", cols = 10, widths = 25)

openXL(wb)
```